# Where are the functions defined for CFS in Linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduling, kernel

In [sched_class](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/include/linux/sched.h#L1093) for a Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS) there is function prototype defined for `enqueue_task`. Where is the actual function implementation defined? A search got me a definition [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/kernel/sched/core.c#L713) (below). But is that the place where the enqueue of the task happens? If so where is `p->sched_class->enqueue_task`

```
 713 static void enqueue_task(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int flags)
 714 {
 715        update_rq_clock(rq);
 716        sched_info_queued(p);
 717        p->sched_class->enqueue_task(rq, p, flags);
 718 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be assigned to a `sched_class` struct at [kernel/sched/fair.c:5343](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5343) and defined at [kernel/sched/fair.c:2178](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/kernel/sched/fair.c#L2178).